# Regular Expression capture filename and optional extension

Tags: regex, filenames

Given a file path with folder name, file name and an optional file extension, I would like to capture the file name (without extension) and the extension.

For example:

```
"c:\temp\test.txt" -> matches = "test" and ".txt"
"c:\temp\blob"     -> matches = "blob" and ""
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what language?  Most languages have built-in file system manipulation functionality to do this exact thing. Or are you truly looking only for regex solution? I ask as this is typically a simple string manipulation problem, not requiring the flexibility and overhead of regex.

Comment: regex solution only.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should match any characters, a backslash, any non-backslash and non-period characters (filename), and then an optional period and series of non-period/non-backslash characters for the extension.

```
^.*\\([^.\\]+)(\.[^.\\]+)?$
```

Comment: You need to escaped the dot and the backslash

Comment: If he only wants the filename and extension, why to do the regexp to anchor the beginning and use the (always unnecessary) `^.*` prefix?